# How do I download images (jpg) via a webclient and save to isolated storage on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient, isolatedstorage

Due to my lack of programming experience (3 months) I have been unable to recreate any found examples of the above question. The examples I have found relate to non WP7 Silverlight, camera based saving of images, have been to complex for my needs or have just not worked. I have been able to download a text file using an instance of the Webclient and save it to isolated storage using StreamWriter. I need to acomplish the same task with jpg images. Below is what I have used to download the text file.

===============================================================================

```
 IsolatedStorageFile MyStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();


    private void GetTextFile()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new     DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/textfile.txt"));
        }

    private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,     DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter MyStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(new     IsolatedStorageFileStream("textfile.txt", FileMode.Create, MyStore));
            MyStreamWriter.WriteLine(e.result)
            MyStreamWriter.Close();
    }
```

===============================================================================

I have removed a few lines used to handle errors etc to keep it as simple as posible.

Please could someone modify the above to enable me to download and save a jpg?

Please keep it as simple as possible as I am easily confused.

Thank you for your time in advance!

RESOLVED!===============================================================================

I managed to get it working using information from this site below.
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/operating-image-files-windows

Hopefully this will help other frustrated newbie's in the future!

```
IsolatedStorageFile MyStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

private void GetImageFile()
{
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new     OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/1.jpg"), client);
    }


void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     var resInfo = new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, null);
 var reader = new StreamReader(resInfo.Stream);
 byte[] contents;
     using (BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(reader.BaseStream))
    {
     contents = bReader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length);
    }
     IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = MyStore.CreateFile("10.jpg");
 stream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
 stream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one, Maybe helpfull to You,

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest reqest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    reqest1.BeginGetResponse(DownloadImageCallback, reqest1);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

void DownloadImageCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{

    HttpWebRequest req1 = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)req1.EndGetResponse(result);
    Stream s = responce.GetResponseStream();
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        string directory = "Images";
        if (!myStore.DirectoryExists(directory))
        {
            myStore.CreateDirectory(directory);
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(directory + "//yourfilename.jpg"))
                {
                    var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitimage);
                    var width = wb.PixelWidth;
                    var height = wb.PixelHeight;
                    Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, isoFileStream, width, height, 0, 100);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(directory + "//yourfilename.jpg"))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(directory + "//yourfilename.jpg");
                }

                using (var isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(directory + "//yourfilename.jpg"))
                {
                    var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitimage);
                    var width = wb.PixelWidth;
                    var height = wb.PixelHeight;
                    Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, isoFileStream, width, height, 0, 100);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```